# SignalR client side callbacks are object functions and 'this'

Tags: javascript, signalr

I'm experimenting with SignalR. When my client defined callback is a method belonging to a javascript object then when inside that function (when it's called from SignalR) 'this' refers to the hub object. My question is how can I get the container javascript object so I can access it's variables and functions?

```
var gameLoad = {

    init: function () {
        // create the network object and hook it's functions update for loading
        this.network = $.connection.testHub;
        console.log(this.network);
        this.network.client.hello = this.sayHello;
    },

    // called from signalR 'this' is the network hub object now when inside the function
    sayHello: function () {
        console.log("Test 2!");
        console.log(this);  // <-- this isn't gameLoad object it's SignalR object. how do I access gameLoad object properties/methods?

        play.update();
    },

    create: function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log(this.network);

        // switch to play state passing network along so it can bind to some of it's function
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log("Started!")
            console.log("Calling server function.");

            // make our first network call
            self.network.server.hello();
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an object and storing it in a variable called gameload, so you can access the object via the gameload variable:

```
var gameLoad = {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: function() {
        console.log(gameLoad.foo);
    }
};

gameLoad.bar();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nk4hv96c/

EDIT:

I don't think this next suggestion counts as an answer, as you specifically asked for JavaScript, but when writing JavaScript I use TypeScript.

TypeScript helps give your code more structure and provides useful features like being able to preserve "this" as "the object you're operating in".

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes.html

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

EDIT 2:

If you want to use constructor functions, then you can save "this" to a variable in the constructor function.

```
function Foo() {
    var self = this;

    this.Bar = "Bar";

    this.Baz = function () {
        console.log(self.Bar);  
    };
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.Baz();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8b7kjmau/

This is also how TypeScript handles it: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Bar%20%3D%20%22Bar%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Baz%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.Bar)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D

EDIT 3:

This example shows how "self" is available, even though "this" has been changed.

It uses a jQuery click event rather than SignalR to change "this".

```
function Foo() {
    var self = this;

    this.Bar = "Bar";

    this.Baz = function () {
        console.log(this.self);
        console.log(this.id);
        console.log(self.Bar);
    };
}

var foo = new Foo();

$("#button").click(foo.Baz);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gr7dzgqr/

Output:

```
Undefined
button
Bar
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I could access it via the object name itself and in this case it works, but what if I used class and new to create the object? I'll try this though and given what I wrote this is an answer.

Comment: Hopefully that edit satisfies that curiosity as well!

Comment: The new ES6 seems to give us "classes" in Javascript (don't have to use Typescript). In there it doesn't look like I can do the var self = this idea outside of a function. I could inside the constructor() do this.self = this but doesn't doesn't help as when inside the singalR callback this doesn't refer to that class anymore.

Comment: if you look at EDIT 2 it shows an example of how you can use "self" without doing "this.self". If this.Baz was called by SIgnalR then "self" is passed via a closure and is still availible, even though "this" is now different.As for ES6, it's great, but it's not fully supported by the browsers yet. TypeScript allows you to use ES6 features and compile to ES5, and it provides Type checking at compile time, which ES6 doesn't even go near ;)

Comment: I added edit 3 to show that passing "self" via a closure works fine even when "this" has been modified by the function caller.